# Fortran spherical harmonic function

Tags: fortran

I want to use a Fortran function that simply outputs a real spherical harmonic as a function of the Cartesian coordinates and integers l and m, i.e. Y_lm(r). Does anyone know any code that does this? I may also be interested in the gradient of Y_lm(r) down the road.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking to find or recommend software or code are off-topic.

Comment: Try posting in comp.lang.fortran or Fortran Discourse.  The audience there appear to be receptive to questions of this nature.

Comment: I use GSL for this - but comp.lang.fortran is a better place to ask